# Unable to Start Confluent Platform Services on my local

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I cannot run confluent platform on my local when typing the command

```
confluent local services start
```

I am getting the error below. Please help!

```
Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /var/folders/t6/nggq0s417tj5hr40t184_1y80000gp/T/confluent.095751 panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 0
```

Complete log :

```
 The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /var/folders/t6/nggq0s417tj5hr40t184_1y80000gp/T/confluent.095751
panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local.(*Command).checkJavaVersion(0xc000366990, 0x5f5a876, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local/command_service.go:697 +0x534
github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local.(*Command).checkService(0xc000366990, 0x5f5a876, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local/command_service.go:275 +0x65
github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local.(*Command).startService(0xc000366990, 0xc000368a00, 0x5f5a876, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7, 0xc0001c2540)
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local/command_service.go:249 +0x9a
github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local.(*Command).runServicesStartCommand(0xc000366990, 0xc000368a00, 0xc000415220, 0x0, 0x1, 0x54d07eb, 0xc000368a00)
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/local/command_services.go:217 +0xdf
github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/pkg/cmd.NewCLIRunE.func1(0xc000368a00, 0xc000415220, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/pkg/cmd/cobra.go:13 +0x51
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc000368a00, 0xc000415210, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc000368a00, 0xc000415210)
    pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3-0.20210218152603-eb3b6397b1b5/command.go:855 +0x472
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc0001c1180, 0xc000010010, 0x0, 0x0)
    pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3-0.20210218152603-eb3b6397b1b5/command.go:964 +0x375
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3-0.20210218152603-eb3b6397b1b5/command.go:900
github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd.(*command).Execute(0xc00053c6c0, 0xc00004e0b0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc00053c6c0, 0x8)
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/internal/cmd/command.go:216 +0x7e
main.main()
    src/github.com/confluentinc/cli/cmd/confluent/main.go:37 +0x17e
```

Comment: Try using Docker Compose instead

Comment: But I need the confluent local build

Comment: Why do you need to "build" anything? Also, if you're using an M1 Mac, then I don't think confluent supports that, and you'd therefore need to still use Docker

Comment: Thanks. I am not using an M1 mac. I will try Docker.